# Rails: getting logic to run at end of request, regardless of filter chain aborts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, controller, filter, action-filter

Is there a reliable mechanism discussed in rails documentation for calling a function at the end of the request, regardless of filter chain aborts?

It's not after filters, because after filters don't get called if any prior filter redirected or rendered.

For context, I'm trying to put some structured profiling/reporting information into the app log at the end of *every* request. This information is collected throughought the request lifetime via instance variables wrapped in custom controller accessors, and dumped at the end in a JSON blob for use by a post-processing script.

My end goal is to generate reports about my application's logical query distribution (things that depend on controller logic, not just request URIs and parameters), performance profile (time spent in specific DB queries or blocked on webservices), failure rates (including invalid incoming requests that get rejected by before_filter validation rules), and a slew of other things that cannot really be parsed from the basic information in the application and apache logs.

At a higher level, is there a different "rails way" that solves my app profiling goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a middleware that can execute code after the application has finished the request. See for more information in the guide: http://guides.rails.info/rails_on_rack.html

Updated link: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Comment: How would I pass information to the rack application - a response header? I still need a mechanism to reliably add such a header at the end of any request, regardless of filter chain aborts, so, doesn't the problem remain unchanged?

Comment: Update here: without an always-run post-request hook mechanism directly supported from rails, the best one can do is stash information in the rack environment as it becomes available and then use a rack middleware to log it. you can also be verbose in the rack environment data stash and summarize it in the middleware if need be, so the rails mechanism is not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

around filters should solve this problem today: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods

(really old thread - but came across this before I found the answer)

Comment: While true that around filters are an improvement over after filters for this purpose, there are normal scenarios in which they will not finish running, such as on an exception (e.g., ActiveRecord::NotFound). In that case the "after" phase of the around filter still won't run. So I think rack middleware remains the most reliable solution, and note in Rails 3 it needs to be in the middleware stack "above" ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions where such exceptions are trapped and handled.